# wxFreeChart value-label chart

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

Is it possible to create simple chart using wxFreeChart with Y-axis labelled with double values and X-axis labelled with string values? Which type of chart and dataset should I use? I tried to use `XYDynamicSerie` and I like it, but it can mess with pair double-double.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by 'X-axis holding string values'.  I assume you mean something else than that the X-Axis is labelled with string values, but I cannot guess what it could be.

Comment: Yes, I mean "X-Axis is labelled with string values". Sorry, I'm dabbler in english.

Comment: I like your use of the word "dabbler".  I am not familiar with wxFreeChart, but it looks sophisticated.  I cannot imagine that it would have any problem la belling an axis with strings!  Please post the code you use and describe what goes wrong.

Comment: <offtopic> Actually, this usage of word 'dabbler' is not mine. Sir Arthur Conan Doyle used it in 'The Hound of the Baskervilles'.</offtopic> I think, I should do some 'homework' before posting some code. It seems sophisticated to me too.

Comment: I suggest you remove this question, until you can ask it in a form that can be answered.

Comment: It's a really good question. Because, flexibility is one of the core principles of wxFreeChart. Thanks for your feedback. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an author of wxFreeChart.

Charts, where one axis has string values use CategoryDataset.

Line charts, with CategoryDataset are not supported. Only bar charts (BarPlot).